How many dimensions are in string theory?
How many dimensions are in string theroy? I heard that there are 11 but to my understanding, there is an infinite, also can strings be on a 2D plane?

"but to my understanding, there is an infinite" Why?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31882/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/292919/2451 and links therein.
