# Why M-theory has eleven dimensions?

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, spacetime-dimensions, quantum-anomalies

Why M-theory has exactly 10+1 dimensions?
Some combinatorics with tensor indices will do.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10126/2451 and links therein.

Comment: See also [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31882).

Comment: @Qmechanic I can see **no** detailed reference to my OQ in your links.

Comment: The dimensions required in bosonic string theory ($26$), supersymmetric string theory ($10$) and M-theory ($11$) do not admit explanations rooted in "combinatorics with tensor indices". If on the other hand you asked why M-theory has exactly one more dimension than supersymmetric string theory, and didn't constrain how we're expected to answer, that... would probably be a duplicate anyway. But it'd be a question much better suited to this site.